# IntelliJ IDEA + Tomee 1.7.1 - Bean Manager not found error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-tomee, bean-manager

I'm getting a strange error when starting up tomee in IntelliJ and deploying my web app (as war).  I'm not referencing any bean manager or weld classes in my pom.xml file and so far this is just a "bare bones" web application that I'm using to try out TomEE and do a bit of fun stuff with it (hopefully) - but this error is blocking me - any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
    Mar 24, 2015 10:55:32 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatResourceFactory create
SEVERE: Can't create resource BeanManager
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:129)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatResourceFactory.create(TomcatResourceFactory.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Thanks @tkoenig - I found out what the problem was - I had a context.xml that had a version of Weld's CDI BeanManager registered (from another project).  I removed it and redeployed - now it works ....!